# Apply [EnableQuery] attribute of OData Globally in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, odata

In ASP.NET I'm able to Enable Query support Globally using following lines of code.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.EnableQuerySupport();
}
```

OData recently reliesed their beta2 version of AspNetCore.OData. Using which we can enable query support at action level using [EnableQuery]
Do we have any similar code as in ASP.NET where I can enable globally in ASP.NET core OData

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension method :

```
public static IMvcBuilder EnableODataQuery(this IMvcBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute());
    });
    return builder;
}
```

And call it "in Startup.cs" like this :

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().EnableODataQuery();
```